# PySide2 Model Contents Disappearing

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I wanted to share a solution to a problem I encountered where `QStandardItem` models were being cleared at seemingly random intervals.

### The Faulty Code:

```py
addr = []
while isinstance(item, QtGui.QStandardItem):
    coordinates = (item.row(), item.column())
    addr.insert(0, coordinates)
    item = item.parent()   # <--- this line is problem

gc.collect()  # triggers item deletion
```

Recursing through item parents, and assigning them to a variable causes them to be marked ready for garbage collection.

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, post a report on the [pyside bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE). There's no point in reporting here.

Comment: sorry, I will do that instead then.

Comment: No problem. Please add a link to the tracker issue to your answer, as it may be useful to others having similar problems.

Comment: no, I'm closing this again. I'm sorry.

This definitely fixed it within the codebase, but I cannot reproduce it in a simple example.
I must be doing something else that is the real cause of the issue, and avoiding this is just sidestepping the issue.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

### The Fixed Code:

Use `QModelIndex`es instead.

```py
index = item.index()    
addr = []
while index.isValid():
    coordinates = (index.row(), index.column())
    addr.insert(0, coordinates)
    index = index.parent()

gc.collect()  # nothing gets deleted now :)
```